# Changing the css style causes the keyboard to disappear on Android device when the input box is clicked

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I have a search box and a search icon. The search box has the style {display:none;} on smaller devices. When the search icon is clicked, the search box toggles using jQuery.

```
$("#search-icon").click(function(){
    $("#searchbox").toggle("slow");
});
```

When I click on the search box, the keyboard shortly appears and disappears on an android device. But it works fine on iphone.

If there is no css property such as {display:none;} and if the search box is visible without having to click the search icon, then the search box works perfectly. I figured that it has  to do something with the {display:none;} property.

Is there any other way to make sure that the search box drops down / toggles when you click on the search icon and still work on Android devices?

Comment: Is this a native app hosting HTML or a web app viewed in a mobile browser?

Comment: Hi, It is a responsive web application viewed in a mobile.

Comment: So on Android, are you testing with the stock browser, and have you tried other browsers, e.g. Chrome? I suspect more of a browser issue than a platform issue. In any case, maybe try removing the inline style (instead of or before the toggle): `$("#searchbox").css("display", "");`

Comment: I tried it in chrome. It doesn't work. Amd like u said, I tried adding "$(#searchbox).css("display","none")". It is the same thing. The keyboard shortly appears and disappears.